# Access Report Subgroup summing

Tags: ms-access, report

In MS Access 2010, assume a query contains the following results:

```
Date     Activity     Hours
1.9.     Reading      1
1.9.     Writing      2
2.9.     Reading      1
3.9.     Talking      1
4.9.     Reading      3

1.10.    Talking      2
1.10.    Writing      1
2.10.    Reading      2
3.10.    Talking      2
4.10.    Reading      1
```

the Report should show the sum of hours spent each month grouped by activity, something like

```
Month           Activity            Hours
September       Reading             5
                Writing             2
                Talking             1

October         Reading             3
                Writing             1
                Talking             4
```

using the wizard I mange to get a report which looks like

```
Month           Activity            Hours
September       Reading             1
                Reading             1
                Reading             3
                Writing             2
                Talking             1

October         Reading             2
                Reading             1
                Writing             1
                Talking             2
                Talking             2
```

which is nearly what I'd like to have but.. ?

I tried =sum(Hours), but then all Hours fields simply contain the total sum of all hours, and I still get several lines for the same activity.

Actually the report is more complicated. In a form prior to the report, the user can enter a date range (e.g. September 1 - October 30). The report should sum over the whole time range and not break up to months, that is:

```
Date range      Activity            Hours
9/1 - 10/30     Reading             8
                Writing             3
                Talking             5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a query with a SQL like this:

```sql
SELECT MonthName(Month([Date])), Activity, SUM(Hours)
FROM yourTable
WHERE [Date] >= xxx AND [Date] <= yyy
GROUP BY MonthName(Month([Date])), Activity
```

The key element is the GROUP BY clause, it sums the Hours per Month + Activity.

Then base your report on that query.

BTW, it is not a good idea to call a column "Date", it's a reserved word in Access.

Comment: Yes, this solution works in the simple example. In my real DB things are more complicated. Prior to the report I show a mask where the user can select a date range (e.g. 2.2.2015 - 5.5.2015). I pass that date range as a filter to the report, which works fine.
Now I'd have to somehow include that date range in the GROUP BY clause...? Or can I somehow tell it to GROUP BY Date, simply ignoring the contents and treating all Dates alike?

Comment: and yes, in the real DB the field name is "Eingang", not "Date" :)

Comment: That's good. :) You can have a WHERE clause in a GROUP BY query just like in a normal query. See edit. xxx and yyy should probably refer to fields in your filter form, so it can work as record source for the report.

Comment: yes, but that would still group by month name. If the range spans two or more months, I still want only one hours field in the report?

Comment: Huh? I thought the whole point was to group by month and activity? "the Report should show the sum of hours spent **each month** grouped by activity".  --- If you don't want that, simply remove `MonthName(Month([Date]))` from the GROUP BY clause.